# Implementing Oneway Grain to Grain Media Streaming with Different Nodes and Silos in the Same Cluster

Tags: c#, .net, stream, microservices, orleans

**Description:**
I'm trying to implement a one-way grain to grain media streaming system using Orleans, where the sender and receiver grains are located on different nodes and silos within the same cluster. The goal is to efficiently stream media data between grains without storing it persistently in the cluster.

**Issue:**
I'm facing challenges in configuring Orleans to support this scenario. The application uses gRPC endpoints for both nodes, meaning each node has a different gRPC endpoint for clients to get the response data. Specifically, I'm unsure about how to set up the communication between grains on different nodes and silos, ensuring efficient data transfer without unnecessary network overhead.

**Questions:**
How can I configure Orleans to support one-way media streaming between grains on different nodes and silos, considering the use of different gRPC endpoints for each node?
Are there any best practices or guidelines for implementing such a system in Orleans?
Are there any specific considerations or limitations I should be aware of when implementing this feature?

**Additional Context:**
I have already implemented a basic grain-to-grain communication within the same node and silo, but I'm struggling to extend this to support communication between grains on different nodes and silos.

Any help or guidance on this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: share your grain method setup.  The fact that your mentioning gRPC implies your not using the grain interfaces correctly

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.